# Image width not working in safari retina

Tags: html, css

Made a website for a friend and he wanted a logo-link in the bottom of the screen. Looks fine on my PC but on his MacBook it is much bigger. Please help.
My CSS is:

```
img.crossfitnorth {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 100px !important;
}
```

[image: This is on his Mac]

[image: This is on my PC]

Comment: I can't reproduce it on any browser on Mac OS. Maybe a cache issue?

Comment: @McVenco So it looks fine on every browser you've tried? Maybe a cache then..